# In Rails how do I avoid needing to use yaml_unsafe_load for Psych::DisallowedClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am ugprading a rails app to 6.1.7 and there is a security concern with active record:
https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/cve-2022-32224-possible-rce-escalation-bug-with-serialized-columns-in-active-record/81017

Many tests are failing on a line like the one below:

```
Given('that there are {int} past events') do |number|
  number.times do
    create(:event_instance,
           category: 'Scrum',
           created_at: rand(1.months.seconds.to_i).seconds.ago,
           project_id: nil)
  end
end
```

The discussions I find say I should able to work around the problem temporarily using `config.active_record.use_yaml_unsafe_load` in application.rb, but the only way to resolve the problem so the test passes is with this:

```
    config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [
       Symbol,
       ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess,
       ActionController::Parameters
    ]
```

Can anyone tell me the problem with the step above, or how to fix it so I don't need the workaround at all?  I can post other steps that are failing if needed.

```
Given I have some videos on project “hello world”                   # features/step_definitions/youtube_steps.rb:33
      Tried to load unspecified class: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (Psych::DisallowedClass)
      <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap’
      ./features/step_definitions/youtube_steps.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
      ./features/step_definitions/youtube_steps.rb:43:in `times’
      ./features/step_definitions/youtube_steps.rb:43:in `/^the project “(.*?)” has (\d+) videos of user “(.*?)“$/'
      ./features/step_definitions/youtube_steps.rb:34:in `/^I have some videos on project “(.*?)“$/'
      features/users/user_videos.feature:33:in `I have some videos on project “hello world”'
```

Comment: the error from the cucumber test is this:
Tried to load unspecified class: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (Psych::DisallowedClass)

Comment: *"Many tests are failing on a line like the one below:"* What is actually failing? Why do you believe it has to do with this CVE (I can't see anything here that suggests that). Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: I added the trace.  Here's the updates made so far.  Maybe another gem needs updating?
https://github.com/AgileVentures/WebsiteOne/pull/3815

Answer (score 0):

A few models used active record serialization, so just making sure they use JSON instead of YAML fixed it:

```
serialize :participants, JSON
```

Update:  Adding JSON to the serialize statement like above works, but we found it better to take out 'serialize' and change the datatype in the database to 'json,' which supports lists of things itself:

```
class ChangeParticipantsInEventInstances < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    change_column :event_instances, :participants, "json USING CAST(participants AS json)"
    change_column_default :event_instances, :participants, []
  end
end
```